# Circularly shifting associative array?

Tags: php, associative-array

Working in PHP, assume you have an associative array:

```
'Monday' => 'mon'
'Tuesday' => 'tue'
'Wednesday' => 'wed'
'Thursday' => 'thur'
'Friday' => 'fri'
'Saturday' => 'sat'
'Sunday' => 'sun'
```

How could you perform a "circular" array shift? Say shifting things so that the array starts with Wednesday, and proceeds through all 7 days, ending with Tuesday?

An important note: I need to do this by key, as I have other code determining what day the shift needs to start at.

Comment: Do you mean shifting then pushing the values back to the end of the array?

Comment: Essentially. In my example, removing Monday and Tuesday, and pushing to the end of the array achieves the goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No looping required

```
 $arr=array('Monday' => 'mon',
'Tuesday' => 'tue',
'Wednesday' => 'wed',
'Thursday' => 'thur',
'Friday' => 'fri',
'Saturday' => 'sat',
'Sunday' => 'sun');
//say your start is wednesday
$key = array_search("Wednesday",array_keys($arr));
$output1 = array_slice($arr, $key); 
$output2 = array_slice($arr, 0,$key); 
$new=array_merge($output1,$output2);
print_r($new);
```

Comment: This answer is great because it saves a loop, plus I can actually run math. If I want Tuesday, but the key I'm given to work with is Wednesday, I can simply subtract 1 from the key.

Answer (score 3):

```
function curcle_shift($arr, $n) {
  return array_slice($arr, $n % 7) + array_slice($arr, 0, $n % 7);
}

// ex. shift the first 2.
var_dump(curcle_shift($arr, 2));
```

Comment: Yes, this function is deleting values

Answer (score 1):

Shifting an array while maintaining array keys:

```
function shiftArray($arr, $key) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if ($k == $key) break;
        unset($arr[$k]);
        $arr[$k] = $v;
    }
    return $arr;
}

print_r(shiftArray($arr, 'Wednesday'));
/*
Array
(
    [Wednesday] => wed
    [Thursday] => thur
    [Friday] => fri
    [Saturday] => sat
    [Sunday] => sun
    [Monday] => mon
    [Tuesday] => tue
)
 */
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I need to do it by key. It won't always be in the same place.

Comment: If your keys are not in proper order, you'll need a second, numerically indexed array containing the keys in the order you want them. It would then be this second array that you should perform shifts and pushes on. Also, `$arr[] = array_shift($arr);` is marginally better than using `array_push()`

Comment: Works like a mf'ng dream. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

```
$key = array_keys($arr)[0]; // use a temporary variable in PHP before 5.4
$val = $arr[$key];
unset($arr[$key]);
$arr[$key] = $val;
```

This will take the first key, save its value, remove it from the array, then add it again (which will put it at the end of the array).

Answer (score 1):

Slice, merge, handle by reference.

```
function shiftArray( &$a, $k ) {
    $k = array_search( $k, array_keys( $a ) );
    $a = array_merge( array_slice( $a, $k ), array_slice( $a, 0, $k ) );
}

shiftArray( $week, "Wednesday" );
```

Since this works by reference, `$week` itself has been restructured. No new array.

Demo: http://codepad.org/uITGdMKy

Answer (score 0):

```
while (key($arr) !== $pivotKey) {
    list($k, $v) = each($arr);
    unset($arr[$k]);
    $arr[$k] = $v;
}
```

make sure the key exists before entering the loop.